# Docker container has a default route I didn't configure

Tags: docker, networking

I've set up a semi-optimal IPv6 environment, so nginx running in the container can see the real source IPv6 address instead of the IPv4 userland proxy one from Docker. I confirmed this by looking into nginx logs. To achieve this, I set up a Docker bridge network named `ipv6_net` with a `fd00:f00d:abcd::/112` subnet, but I didn't explicitly define the gateway that containers on this can use. For the nginx container to receive and respond to traffic, I set up some DNAT and MASQUERADE ip6tables rules on the host Docker is running on.

The rules are as follows:

```
 18  1448 DNAT    tcp   enx207bd2bbdc95 *    ::/0            ::/  0            tcp dpt:80 to:[fd00:f00d:abcd::2]:80
 29  2296 DNAT    tcp   enx207bd2bbdc95 *    ::/0            ::/  0            tcp dpt:443 to:[fd00:f00d:abcd::2]:443

 ...

  0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp    *    enx207bd2bbdc95  ::/0            ::  /0                 tcp spt:80
  0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp    *    enx207bd2bbdc95  ::/0            ::  /0                 tcp spt:443
```

`enx207bd2bbdc95` is my host network interface where it has WAN access. For the ingoing packets (host -> nginx), I can understand that these packets are properly forwarded to the container since its IPv6 address is specified and the host has the virtual interface provided by Docker with which it can reach the container's subnet. However, I do not understand the process of the container sending out packets. How does the container know where it can send the packet to for it to respond to clients that are not on its subnet (basically all clients)? It doesn't have a standard gateway after all... right?

A `docker network inspect ipv6_net` gives this:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "ipv6_net",
        "Id": "ebd226bb03287c1134cb2a7bb7553a2a270f3c2fcfb64ff0b8df1ab7739e856c",
        "Created": "2023-11-20T19:43:15.031380888+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": true,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.28.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.28.0.1"
                },
                {
                    "Subnet": "fd00:f00d:abcd::/112"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "d19f6181bea605684c2a031abc2de1329fdd227f5ff703a8f22dd049c5f443a6": {
                "Name": "nginx",
                "EndpointID": "3c503dd7990770029f3e44ba0c5aef2e30a2948584a7c37145beadb626641ad5",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1c:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.28.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": "fd00:f00d:abcd::2/112"
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

But it turns out:

Executing `docker compose exec nginx ip -6 route show` tells that there is a default route to `fd00:f00d:abcd::1` (docker interface for host), which explains that there is a gateway configured, although I didn't specify it at any point. When is this set? Did Docker set this route?